# How can we convert String to Map in Java if comma is present in either key or value in `the string?

Tags: java, string, hashmap

Lets say we have,

```
String value = "{name = abc, address = xyz, abc, school = mno}"
```

How can we convert this string into a Map as we split the key value pair of the string with comma? Here when I try to split with comma I get an error saying no value for key abc as address = xyz acts as a key value pair.

Any generic approach will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you expect map to return for key `abc` in your example?

Comment: The first step is to define what the semantics actually are (as Ostap Andrusiv was getting at). At that point, you have a language: now you "just" need to write a parser for it. Lucky for you, this already exists, in a form pretty close to what you have already. The language is JSON, and there are lots of parsers out there for it.

Comment: So is this a case where you have a key "address" with a value "xyz, abc", or is this a case where you have a key "abc, school" and a value "mno"? You see what you are saying is ambiguous and if you can't decide what it should be, how can a deterministic program do it then?

Comment: Ya Erwin I have a key with "address" and value with "xyz, abc".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to create a map in which the entry with the key `address` has `xyz, abc` as value.

You can use regex for this. Here is an example:

```
String s = "{name = abc, address = xyz, abc, school = mno}";
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (String element : s.replaceAll("[{}]", "").split("(,(?=[^,]+=))")) {
    String[] entry = element.split("=");
    map.put(entry[0].trim(), entry[1].trim());
}
```

What this does is to first remove all `{` and `}` character from the `String` and split that `String` on every `,` that is followed by a sequence of characters that doesn't contain a `,` and ends in a `=` character.

Comment: Thanks the solution is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a function which should solve your problem.
Maybe your IDE shows some syntax errors, if so, you have to corrent them yourself. I used Notepad in this example.

Here are a few steps to get the result you want, followed by the code:

1. Remove the brackets
2. Split the string by each comma ","
3. Split every single resulting String again by the equal sign "="
4. Put the first Array index as key and second Array index as value into your map.
   (optional) call .trim() on the Array indices first to remove white spaces.

So here is an example function:

```
    public void ParseToMap(String data, Map<String, String> map)
    {
        //Make sure we don't run into trouble
        if(data == null || data.isEmpty() || map == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Splits by ','
        String[] keyValuePairs = data.substring(1,data.length()-2).split(",");

        for(int i = 0; i < keyValuePairs.length(); i++)
        {
            // Splits by '='
            String _tmp = keyValuePairs[i].split("="); 
            if(_tmp.length() > 1)
            {
                String key =    _tmp[0].trim(); // Get the key + remove useless spaces
                String value =  _tmp[1].trim(); // Get the value + remove useless spaces

                map.put(key, value); // Insert the pair
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would improve your answer to explain your code logic a little.

Comment: I`ll keep it in mind :)

Comment: If you already implemented this code, **please update it**. I have added an additional if-statement to ensure everything works fine, even if you have a key without value!

Answer (score 0):

As other said in comments, you should be using a JSON parser to handle this.

With that said, we can still provide some code that will be able to handle your example string (but would most likely fail for some other examples) :

```
String value = "{name = abc, address = xyz, abc, school = mno}";
Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();

String[] parts = value.replaceAll("[{}]", "").split(",");
for (String part : parts) {
    String[] operands = part.split("=");
    if (operands.length == 2) { // we have a x = y pattern
        result.put(operands[0].trim(), operands[1].trim());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can **split** your `String` in two level to get the **key/value** couple :

```
String value = "name = abc, address = xyz, abc, school = mno";
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

String [] values = value.split(", ");

for (String couple : values){   
    if(couple.contains(" = ")) {
        String [] subValues = couple.split(" = ");
        map.put(subValues[0], subValues[1]);
    }else{
        map.put(couple, null);
    }   
}
```

> **Note :**    you should get **rid** of the brackets **{}** in your `String` value  before

Comment: You should take a look into your resulting map ...

Comment: It's fault of inattention !!! if you notice i have get rid of the brackets and i have **mentionned** that !!! .. Anyway i have updated my answer and thks for the minus ;)

Comment: *"if you notice i have get rid of the brackets and i have mentionned that !!!"* I wasn't talking about the brackets. I was talking about the silently removed *"abc"* String (I guess the first sentence in my comment wasn't already clear). *"and thks for the minus ;)"* You've posted bad, non-working code, what else do you expect?

Comment: *"You should test it before saying bullshit ;)"* You write that and simultaneously update your code since it was wrong? This is just pathetic.

Comment: pfff .. the code works fine try to tested it yourself ! have a nice day

Comment: It _now_ works fine, after you've fixed it several times.

Comment: i fixed it when you said that there is  no "abc" in the value ! plz let's stop this kind of discussion !